# Is there a way to automatically prepend a string to all selected fields in a table?

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have a select with a join.
I know that I can do this:

```
table1.id as table1_id, table1.name as table1_name
```

I was wondering if it's possible to do it automatically when selecting fields in this way:

```
table1.*
```

I completely understand that this is bad practice, but it's useful for local testing and I was wondering if it was possible to do something like this.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend adding some additional context to your id and name field names (for example, if you had tables Person and Employer you might use person_id and employer_id as the field names).

In lieu of changing your table structure, I don't think you can automatically prepend your table names to the fields you could select. But, you could create a view for your query, then in your application, select from the view. Consider this example:

```
+-------------+     +-------------+
| Person      |     | Employer    |
+-------------+     +-------------+ 
| id          |     | id          |
| name        |     | name        |
| employer_id |     +-------------+
+-------------+   

CREATE VIEW PersonEmployer AS
SELECT 
  person.id as `person_id`, 
  person.name as `person_name`, 
  employer.id as `employer_id`, 
  employer.name as `employer_name`
FROM 
 Person 
 INNER JOIN Employer ON (Person.employer_id = Employer.id);

SELECT * FROM PersonEmployer;
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how much views impacts on speed?